# How to format a decimal number to 2 or 3 digits?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, decimal, rounding

I'm writing a convertor by Eclipse and my results are with 9 or 10 decimal digits and I want to make it 2 or 3.
This is part of my code:

```
double gr = 0;
if (edtGr.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
    gr = Float.parseFloat(edtGr.getText().toString());
}
if (edtNgr.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
    gr = (Double.parseDouble(edtNgr.getText().toString())) / 1000000000;
}

edtNgr.setText("" + (gr * 1000000000));
edtGr.setText("" + gr);
```

This code converts grams to nanograms and I want the result in 2 or 3 decimal digits.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2 Decimal places change your code as

```
edtNgr.setText(""+ ((String.format("%.2f", (gr * 1000000000)))));
edtGr.setText("" + ((String.format("%.2f", gr))));
```

And for 3 Decimal points

```
  edtNgr.setText("" + ((String.format("%.3f", (gr * 1000000000)))));
  edtGr.setText("" + ((String.format("%.3f", gr))));
```

Also You can use `DecimalFormat`. One way for (using 3 points) to use it:

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
 df.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
 edtNgr.setText("" + df.format(gr * 1000000000));
 edtGr.setText("" +df.format(gr));
```

Please see more at [How to format Decimal Number in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-format-decimal-number-in-java.html)

Comment: wow!! great answer.. best answer for a beginner like me.thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3739774 Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted,so it may help others also.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
String.format("%.2f", gr * 1000000000);
```

For 3 decimal places,

```
String.format("%.3f", gr * 1000000000);
```

Comment: tnx.but I`m a beginner and I couldnt understand how to use the code to wrote.. whould u please explain more ??

Comment: Read @Giru Bhai's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
double roundOff = Math.round(yourDouble * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
```

Another way

```
BigDecimal doubleVal = new BigDecimal("123.13698");
BigDecimal roundOff = doubleVal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NumberFormatter` like

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
```

then format it like

```
formatter.format(36.55468865)
```

This will give the output `36.555` rounding off `55468865` to `555`

Answer (score 0):

(double)Math.round(value * 100000) / 100000.. the number of precision  indicated by the number of zeros.

Or

double d = 12345.2145;

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
d = bd.doubleValue();

Change the 1st argument in setScale method as per the precision required.